# On geometry of light's path in the Universe

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, gravitational-lensing

Is it possible for us to see our own galaxy from different perspective, as path of light emitted from our galaxy is curved by any possible ways and travelled back to our eyes even if it take much time?

Comment: The simple answer is no, we can't see ourselves. The universe is, as far as we can tell, flat, which means that everything we are looking at is, except for minor gravitational lensing, "in a straight line" from us. Since we can see all the way back to the cosmic microwave background, i.e. way before there were even galaxies, we are pretty much looking at a cross section of the (almost) entire history of the universe, it's just not our history but that of ever more distant places.

Comment: @CuriousOne Isn't it possible for light to take an U-turn around a black-hole?

Comment: No. Light doesn't behave like ray optics suggests and it can't be bent backwards like that.

Comment: @CuriousOne Can bending backward happen by means of collective gravitational lensing, one after the other?

Comment: No, it can't. A lensing object will not only bend the light path but it will also cause diffraction, making it impossible to reconstruct the image of a far away object.

Comment: @ACuriousMind By coherence I meant or wanted to say same as what CuriousOne said above.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Isn't this question an exact duplicate of the one you already answered (better than the accepted answer): http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225693/using-a-black-hole-as-a-mirror/225697

Comment: @pela: Is it? This one was about the global geometry, wasn't it? The black hole mirror only came up in the comment. The answer is always the same.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Well, I don't know, actually.

Comment: @ShafkathullahIhsan, do you mean if light from our galaxy could be bend by an object in the Universe back in our direction? Or do you mean if it could travel on and on, but due to the global geometry of our Universe, it would eventually reach us again? In the first case, the answer is given by CuriousOne. In the second case, in principle it could be possible, if it weren't for dark energy accelerating the expansion. If we lived in a positively curve universe without DE, light could make it "round" the universe, although it would reach us exactly when the universe collapsed (so in practice no).

Comment: @pela [This](http://s20.postimg.org/ukavm9lv1/Presentation1.jpg) was what I meant.Link you provided was helpful.

Comment: Okay, interesting setup. In that case the "diffraction" that CuriousOne describes is less. But in order not to diffract the rays from our Galaxy too much, the de_flection_ can't be more than a few arcminutes [citation needed; probably even less], which means that in order to deflect it back 180º, you'll need so many lenses lined up in a perfect setup that 1) it's extremely improbable, and 2) the little diffraction that you _do_ get per lensing event adds up to distorting the image too much anyway. I'd think. I haven't done any calculations.

Comment: maybe it would be interesting to try it (simply) https://stackoverflow.com/q/77014313/11918074 . The reprojection scripts at the end of the day could be interesting..

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is 'yes, in theory, but no in practice'.

First of all, bear in mind that a black hole can deflect light through an arbitrarily large angle: if you've seen the images of the black hole in *Interstallar* then it has these strange patterns around it which are because light can circle it many times before escaping.  (Formally, this is pretty much an argument from continuity, although I think it was a surprising effect!)

So, in particular, a black hole can deflect light back the way it came.

So all you need is a quiescent black hole (no accretion disk or other stuff to confuse the issue) and some light from any source will be deflected back the way it came.  Well, let's assume there is at least one such black hole 'visible' to us, then at least some light from the galaxy is going to be deflected back to it.

So in that sense, some light from the galaxy will clearly be visible to us having been deflected around such an object.

However:

- this will be a ludicrously tiny amount of light;
- I suspect strongly that there will be no useful *image* of the galaxy visible;
- knowing where to look would be extremely hard, since the BH needs to be quiescent and there would therefore not be any interesting EM (or, now, gravitational) radiation reaching us from it to tell us where it is.

So: yes in theory but no in practice.

Answer (score -2):

Most of light emitted either reach other galaxies or escape to cosmological horizon. Our galaxies gravitational force is no enough to deflect it back.

Also, if it is deflected by some other black holes in a pattern,
To get a complete veiw of galaxy we need  light rays to simultaneously deflect back to us.
Such possibility of a limited no. of such rays to to get to us is nill.

Comment: *"escape to event horizon"*, *"we need infinite no. of photons to simultaneously deflect back to us in coherence"*..I'm afraid I have no idea what those phrases are supposed to mean.

Comment: @ACuriousMind What do we say to brink of universe?

Comment: There is no "brink of universe" - for all we know, the universe is infinite and boundaryless. Are you talking about the horizon of the *observable universe* (that's called the particle or cosmological horizon, not the event horizon, which is the horizon of a black hole)?

Answer (score -2):

I know the context is bending of space by heavy bodies, but that is lensing effect and we know lenses do not reflect, however small their focal length is.

Even if it was possible to reflect/turn back good amount of light somehow, it would be next to impossible to see a meaningful image.

When moon reflects sunlight, we see moon, not the sun!

We can see sun's image in water, so, it would be only possible if there was a mirror type of object in universe and happen to be positioned just right for us. Which we know is not there.

Comment: Its not about reflection, its about deflection by means of gravitational force.

Comment: I clarified that in my first line.

Comment: But all optical lenses do reflect some light...